# Why does Dir#glob not populate my variable on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, glob

I have the following Ruby script which is supposed to insert the names of the files into the *contents* array:

```
filelist = Dir.glob('C:\Users\abc\Desktop\drg\*.*')
print filelist
filelist.each do |filepathname|
    contents = IO.read(filepathname)
    puts contents
end
```

For the above code, I get no output for *filelist* or *contents*. Why is that?

Comment: The directory contains .txt files. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does switching the path to `c:/Users/abc/Desktop/drg/*` make it pull a list of files?

Answer (score 2):

### Use File#join

In your current string, the backslash acts as an escape character, not a path separator. A more verbose, but potentially more canonical, approach is to use [File#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-join) to join the parts of your path using File::SEPARATOR. For example:

```
path = File.join "C:", "Users", "abc", "Desktop", "drg", "*.*"
Dir.glob path
```

A side-benefit of this approach is that you can inspect the *path* variable to ensure that it's valid, which is much more testable and debuggable than globbing directly.

Comment: This is the only way I was able to get one of my scripts to work on Windows. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Dir.glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob) uses the backslash as an escape character, so the path will not be what you think it is. To quote:

> Escapes the next metacharacter.
>
> Note that this means you cannot use backslash on windows as part of a glob, i.e. Dir["c:\foo*"] will not work, use Dir["c:/foo*"] instead.